# to_date error while using substr

Tags: sql, database, oracle

When I run:

```
select to_date('substr(21120319,3)','YYMMDD') 
from dual
```

I'm getting the error:

> date is not in the valid range -4719 and +9999.

But if do:

```
select to_date('120319','YYMMDD') 
from dual
```

my query runs fine and gives ouput 19-MAR-12.

What is the reason for this error. Please help me understand this.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why the substr, it would return the wrong century, 21120319 should return 19 march 2112 not 19 march 2012.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to remove substr from the string literal.

```
select to_date(substr('21120319', 3),'YYMMDD') 
from dual ;
```

Comment: You're awesome thanks, Actually I'm trying to cast this to MMDDYY(date target) how can I save it as MMDDYY in target which is a date?

Comment: `to_date(substr('21120319', 3),'YYMMDD') ` results in a `date` so if you're taking that string and want to put it into a `date` field, just insert it. remember that the `date` datatype has NO inherent format. format's are just for viewing the date. i.e. the result of `to_date('12-mar-2012', 'dd-mon-yyyy')` and `to_date('20120312', 'yyyymmdd')` are exactly the same in every single way when converted to a `date` how you view it is entirely up to you and controllable with `to_char()` or the  `nls_date_format` setting

Comment: @user1751356 to see it as `mmddyy`? do `select to_char(your_date_col, 'MMDDYY') alias from yourtable` or... `alter session set nls_date_format='mmddyy';` then all subsequent selects in that session eg: `select your_date_col from your_table` will show that format to you

Comment: so that means if my target column is date i cannot save it as MMDDYY but if i wish i can view it as MMDDYY by setting nls_date_format parameter? do you any documentation related to it. If that is the case then how can my target specification be listed as mmddyy and type as date?

Comment: @user1751356 no you can't save it as a specific format, you simply save it as a `date`. a date internally is stored as a 7bit number. "how can my target specification be listed as mmddyy and type as date" - when you create a date column you don't specify a format eg `create table test(d date);` = no format. if your confused with `to_date('120319','YYMMDD')` having a format, this ONLY means take the string "120319" ,  interpret this as "yymmdd". The format supplied in to_date does not persist with the date itself, and is lost once that conversion is complete.

Comment: If i want to save my data as mmddyy then should i change the data type to varchar? Thanks so much for clearly explaining this.

Comment: @user1751356 i strongly suggest you don't worry about this. do not store dates as varchar2, store them as a date. storing as varchar will only lead to major issues down the line (eg someone will oneday stick a corrupt format in there + histograms get the wrong cardinality for range scans which can give poor plans). just ensure that you `to_char` on select if you need it in a given format.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26475/discussion-between-user1751356-and-dazzal)

Comment: Actually you made an excellent point. This is the best way to deal with it. Saving it as date and then using to_char while reading it. Thanks a ton for your patience, really.

Answer (score 0):

```
select to_date('substr(21120319,3)','YYMMDD')  from dual ;
```

now `substr(21120319,3)` is also part of string

change it to

```
  select to_date(substr('21120319',3),'YYMMDD')  from dual ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need

```
select to_date('21120319','YYYYMMDD') 
from dual
```

No need for the substr, it would return the wrong century, 21120319 should return 19 march 2112 not 19 march 2012.